# Multiple video players in UITableView like in instagram

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, video-streaming

Having a very difficult time creating a UITableView with multiple video players like in Instagram or Facebook. I would like to create a tableview in which each cell has a single functioning video player. MPMoviePlayerController only supports one cell at a time. Any advice or point towards a tutorial would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve it? @scribbler2309

Comment: solved problem?